# how to choose date for date_trunc SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i have worksheet that have periode every month that start from date 25 to 24 (next month).
how to query for pick date on SQL use date_trunc? so when date_trunc(2012-12-29) the result is '2012-12-25' not '2012-12-01'?
thank you~

| Real Date | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-18 | 2022-09-25 |
| 2022-10-20 | 2022-09-25 |
| 2022-10-28 | 2022-10-25 |

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach

```
select RealDate, 
  if(
    extract(day from date(RealDate)) >= 25, 
    date_trunc(date(RealDate), month) + 24, 
    date_sub(date_trunc(date(RealDate), month) + 24, interval 1 month)
  ) as Result
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]